# XPath rule not working in Sonar 4.4

Tags: xpath, sonarqube, rule

reproduce steps:

1. click "Rules" link
2. Search "xpath"
3. click the Java XPath rule that is not deprecated
4. click "create"
5. Fill in "name"/"key"/"Description"/"Message" as "should not use Collections.synchronizedMap" , change status as "ready" , set xpathQuery as `//IDENTIFIER[@tokenValue='synchronizedMap']`
6. click "create" button
7. click "edit" and notice "xpathQuery" field is empty which is unexpected.
8. fill the field "xpathQuery" with `//IDENTIFIER[@tokenValue='synchronizedMap']` again
9. click "save" button
10. click "edit" and notice "xpathQuery" field is missing totally , which is unexpected.
11. run sonar runner again code that contains "Map test = Collections.synchronizedMap()"
12. no issue detected which is unexpected.

As test , Javascript XPath rule doesn't work either, and just test in Sonar 4.3.1 , both Java and Javascript XPath rule works.
java plugin version is 2.4

Anyone please give some suggestion or help reporting it to Sonar JIRA where I didn't have permission to report bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug on SonarQube: [SONAR-5575](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5575)

Its fix is planned and should be available in a month or so. Feel free to vote and watch for the JIRA ticket.

Comment: Thanks. Just wonder when would Sonar 4.5.1 be released , after one month?

Comment: Approximatively, yes.