# Some XPath rule work in SonarQube 4.4

Tags: xpath, sonarqube, rule

Recently I wrote some XPath Query on sonarqube 4.4. Some of them work on sonar 4.4 and some of them not. For example when I defined XPath Queries as following:

1. `//IfStatement/statement[not(block)]`
2. `//WhileStatement/statement[not(block)]`
3. `//variableDeclarator[not(block)]`

the sonar 4.4 detect the issues and when I defined XPath Queries as following:

1. `//qualifiedIdentifier/IDENTIFIER[@tokenValue= "println"]`

the sonar doesn't detect the issues. Why the reason of that?

As Fabrice explain in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887057/xpath-rule-not-working-in-sonar-4-4/25887627#25887627) this is a known bug in sonarqube 4.4 but Why some XPath queries (such as If/Statement) works on sonar 4.4 and another not?

Comment: By downloading the [SSLR Java toolkit](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/java/sslr-java-toolkit/2.4/sslr-java-toolkit-2.4.jar), you'll be able to get the structure of the AST for any java source file and even test your Xpath expression.

Comment: Yes. I downloaded SSLR java toolkit and XPath query works on SSLR java toolkit but in the sonar it doesn't save and doesn't detect the issues.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out this is a known issue :  https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5575

This seems to be related to a bad escaping of the quote when inserting into the database and it explains why some XpathQueries will be persisted and some others won't.